# How to make an existing MySQL table with n number of columns as a MySQLJDBCDataModel in Apache Mahout?

Tags: mysql, mahout

I am trying to create a recommendation system for my project using Mahout. I tried the sample programs(from Mahout) with the .csv files. Now I am using data from MySQL database. I have a table called 'transaction' with the following columns.
`transactionid`, `userid`, `itemid`, `purchasequantity`, `amount`, `rating`

I saw that Mahout needs the data to be in the format "userid , itemid , preference/rating" and I saw that it has the MySQLJDBCDataModel.The required three columns are already there in my 'transaction' table.

Now for the datasource, should I create a new table with only the required 3 columns and copy values from the'transaction' table? Or , can I work with the 'transaction' table itself somehow?

I did go through the documentation in the link below , but couln't understand clearly http://archive.cloudera.com/cdh4/cdh/4/mahout/mahout-integration/org/apache/mahout/cf/taste/impl/model/jdbc/MySQLJDBCDataModel.html

Please advise. Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Do you already have the MySQL JDBC driver in your project?

Comment: Yes , I do. Currently since I don't have many records, I have been fetching the required fields and putting them in  a CSV and using the CSV as the datasource for FileDataModel.

Answer (score 0):

```
By default it assumes  the table schema  

user_id BIGINT NOT NULL,
item_id BIGINT NOT NULL,
preference FLOAT NOT NULL,
```

http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.mahout/mahout-integration/0.7/org/apache/mahout/cf/taste/impl/model/jdbc/MySQLJDBCDataModel.java

long ago i have done like below. i used MySQLBooleanPrefJDBCDataModel.i didnt have preference value.

```
public void datamodelimplementation2()
{
MysqlDataSource dataSource = new MysqlDataSource();
dataSource.setServerName("10.20.53.157");
dataSource.setUser("root");
dataSource.setPassword("root");
dataSource.setDatabaseName("mahout");
DataModel model = new MySQLBooleanPrefJDBCDataModel(dataSource,
"mahoutinput","cid", "pid", null);

ItemBasedRecommender recommender = null;

try {
        DataModel dataModel = new MySQLBooleanPrefJDBCDataModel(dataSource);
        ItemSimilarity similarity = new MySQLJDBCInMemoryItemSimilarity(dataSource);
        AllSimilarItemsCandidateItemsStrategy candidateStrategy =
            new AllSimilarItemsCandidateItemsStrategy(similarity);
          recommender = new GenericItemBasedRecommender(dataModel,
            similarity, candidateStrategy, candidateStrategy);

   } catch (Exception e1) {
  e1.printStackTrace();
 System.exit(-1);
  }

  recommender.refresh(null);
  List<RecommendedItem> r = null;
   try {

  r = recommender.recommend(18768, 10);


 } catch (TasteException e1) {
 // TODO Auto-generated catch block
e1.printStackTrace();
}
System.out.println(r);

}


 as of my knowledge you need to create a table that contains user id,item id,rating. and incrementally add new data to that table.
```